Сколько можно составить различных 3 буквенных слов из данных букв
Есть набор символов (букв): Д (5 шт), Ф (7 шт), К (2 шт), Н (3 шт), А (4 шт). Нужно вычислить количество уникальных последовательностей из этих символов длиной 3 и длиной 4. Помогите, пожалуйста! Это задача, которую никак не могу решить программно методом комбинаторики, без перебирания вариантов. Реализация пойдет через Python, однако, это не играет никакой роли, так как нужен не код, а логика подсчета вариантов.

программно методом комбинаторики Методом комбинаторики - это аналитически, а вовсе даже не программно.

Количество уникальных последовательностей (для 5 букв) длинной 3: 5^3=125. Из этих последовательностей нельзя собрать только ККК => ответ 124

Уточняю, если не понятно был составлен запрос. Программно она решается легко в виде  перебора вариантов. Сейчас же передо мной задача стоит в написании кода основанного на аналитическом подходе. Никак не могу понять логики подсчета вариантов. Прошу помощи у тех, кто разбирается в комбинаторике

@Adel А вы прочитали комментарий needKVAS?

логика подсчета написана где-то на первых 5 страницах любого учебника по комбинаторике

Можно подсчитать рекурсивно.
В общем случае:
Мы должны посчитать количество уникальных слов длинны l (l>0). Пусть k — количество наборов букв, а b - минимальное количество букв (B) в наборе.
Тогда:
В случае если b >= l, то количество уникальных слов равно k^l (Т.к. b минимально).
В случае если b < l:
Пусть i — количество букв B в конечном слове.
Для каждого i ( 0 <= i <= b ) количество вариантов того, как располагаются буквы B в конечном слове, можно определить количеством сочетаний: Сli.
Общее количество конечных слов для каждого варианта можно найти, если перемножить его на количество слов длинны l-i, составленных из наборов букв, среди которых нет набора с буквой B.
Суммарное количество будет искомым.
Таким образом:
import math

def uniq_seq_count(array, length):    
    if not array:
        return 0;
    
    b = array.pop()
    
    if b >= length:
        return pow(len(array)+1, length)
        
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(b+1):
        count += math.comb(length, i) * uniq_seq_count(array[:], length-i)
        
    return count;

a = [5, 7, 2, 3, 4]
l = 3

a.sort(reverse=True)

print (uniq_seq_count(a, l))

